# Adding SQL Server Source Control to Cruise Control.Net

Tags: version-control, continuous-integration, cruisecontrol.net, redgate

We recently acquired Red-Gate's SQL Source Control (Version 2.2) and we want to add the "build" with Cruise Control.Net in our CI Server.

Do anyone knows how to create the scripts to achieve this task? Basically what we want is to build the code AND the database everytime.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Does this help?

http://downloads.red-gate.com/HelpPDF/ContinuousIntegrationForDatabasesUsingRedGateSQLTools.pdf

This gives examples of how to use sqlcompare.exe to deploy a database from SQL Source Control.